# Imagemagick IIS install issue VBScript error "800a01ad"

Tags: iis, installation, permissions, imagemagick

I have Imagemagick running on a remote server and have had it running on a local server successfully for many years, but recently I have had need to reinstall on a new machine and can't for the life of me figure out what i'm doing wrong, It's probably really simple and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
Scenario
WIN 10 running iis as localhost
Successfully installed Imagemagick 32 and 64 bit so they run on the local machine, however when try to access the localhost web page requiring Imagemagic I'm receiving the following message

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
ActiveX component can't create object: 'ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1'

my app pool is current set to allow 32bt application and as far as I am aware all permissions are correct, although I do believe this may be the issue somewhere.

Can anyone help to shed some light on this issue.

Thanks :-)

Comment: What kind of localhost web page? .asp?

Comment: Site is in a virtual directory under win 10, ImageMagick is being called from and ASP page using code line -- Dim img: Set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1"), which then reurn the error message --Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
ActiveX component can't create object: 'ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1'

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.. It turns out the latest version of Imagemagick 7.1.x does not ship with ImagemagickObject.dll, fortunately, I had a saved download .exe for an earlier version 7.0.8 which still had the .dll, once install I could copy imageMagickObject.dll to the system32 folder, after that everything worked as expected. Not sure what would replace this in my code if I have to ever user a newer version, if someone knows please add to the post.